# Sprite kit - Dealing with overlapping animations in fast sequence

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm building an app in which when a sprite is pressed it performs a very simple animation in which the initial image is replaced with a new image and then after a short pause the initial image is applied again. There are 2 of such sprites.

It works all fine unless the buttons are pressed in an extremely rapid sequence. 
Let's say for example that the user presses button 1 and then very quickly afterwards button 2 (before this had the time to revert back to the initial image): in this case button 1 remains stuck with the new image!

Even if I disable the interaction with the sprite (by for example renaming it while the animation is in progress or inserting different flags), still a touchesBegan event is registered and I believe this is enough to get sprite 1 stuck with the new image and not reverting back to the initial one!

I've ran out of ideas... Any suggestions please? Cheers.

```
- (void)SwitchButtonImage
{    
    touchedNode.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:ImageNew]; 

    //After a pause change sprite image to the initial image
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration: 0.3]; 

    [touchedNode runAction: wait completion:^
     {
         touchedNode.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:ImageInitial];
     }];
}

 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{ 
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];         
    [self selectNodeForTouch:positionInScene];
} 

- (void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation 
{
    touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation]; 

    _selectedNode = touchedNode; 

    if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:kButtonNodeName_01]) 
    {[self SwitchButtonImage];} 

    else if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:kButtonNodeName_02]) 
    {[self SwitchButtonImage];}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I edited my answer to handle more than one button and to work with your original code.

```
- (void)SwitchButtonImage
{
    touchedNode.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"NewImage"];

    //After a pause change sprite image to the initial image
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration: 0.3];
    SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"InitialImage"];
    SKAction *resetImage = [SKAction setTexture:texture];

    // Add action with a unique identifier
    [touchedNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, resetImage]] withKey:@"ResetImage"];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    [self selectNodeForTouch:positionInScene];
}


- (void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
    touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];
    _selectedNode = touchedNode;
    if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:kButtonNodeName_01]) {
        // Change image only if previous action is done
        if (![touchedNode actionForKey:@"ResetImage"]) {
            [self SwitchButtonImage];
        }
    }
    else if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:kButtonNodeName_02]) {
        // Change image only if previous action is done
        if (![touchedNode actionForKey:@"ResetImage"]) {
            [self SwitchButtonImage];
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** You can add a key to an SKAction that has a completion block, but you can add a runBlock to the end of an SKAction sequence to do that same. Here's an example:

```
    SKAction *action1 = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1];
    SKAction *action2 = [SKAction rotateByAngle:-M_PI duration:1];
    SKAction *completed = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"I am done");
    }];
    SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:@[action1, action2, completed]];

    [sprite runAction:action withKey:@"actionKey"];
```

Comment: I'd like to try it, but how can I adapt it to my code pls? -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self]; [self selectNodeForTouch:positionInScene];}

- (void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation
{   touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];
    _selectedNode = touchedNode;
    if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:kButtonNodeName_01]) {[self SwitchButtonImage];} else if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:kButtonNodeName_02]) {[self SwitchButtonImage];}}

Comment: I am now implementing a more complex action consisting of different blocks..        


[spriteA runAction: [SKAction repeatAction:action_sequenceA count:1] completion:^
  {
  //Do something
         }];

How can I define this with a key (withKey:@"AnimationA”) so that I can determine when it has finished animating? Thanks!

Comment: See the EDIT 2 section of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using blocks and a BOOL ivar.

Create an ivar:

```
BOOL readyForNextAnimation;
```

Set up your blocks something like this:

```
SKAction *block0 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
                // your animation code here
            }];

SKAction *wait0 = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.3]; // your animation time length

SKAction *block1 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
                readyForNextAnimation = true;
            }];

[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[block0, wait0, block1]]];
```

The above code would then be used something like this:

```
// some trigger just occurred
if(readyForNextAnimation == true)
{
    readyForNextAnimation = false;

    // create blocks 0,1,2 and run them as above
}
```

If you need to do other things, just create more blocks and add them into the run sequence.

Comment: Tried. Thanks. But it does not work as the user can still touch on the sprite while the first animation is in progress and therefore cancel it half way...

Comment: @jeddi - Apply the if(readyForNextAnimation == true) for all your touches in regards to animation of the sprite.

Comment: It did not solve my problem but from your example I learnt how to use blocks better. Interesting. Thank you!